# How to fork and create a specific number of children that perform the same task?

Tags: c, fork, wait

I need to write a C program that calls fork() a given number of times. Each child process needs to perform the same task (adding some random numbers until a given sum is reached). The parent process waits until all of the child processes have exited. I have written the following code but my output shows that another child doesn't start executing its code until the first one is done.

```
for (i = 0; i < num_forks; i++) {
    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid < 0) {
        perror("fork\n");
    } else if (child_pid ==  0) {
        childProcess(i, goal);
    } else {
        parentProcess();
    }
 }
```

**EDIT:** The objective is to have all of the child processes run simultaneously. The parent waits for any of the child processes to exit. As soon as any one child process exits, the parent process prints the pid of the child that exited. The remaining child processes continue to run simulatenously until another child exits and so on. If I call parentProcess() outside of the loop, the parent only prints the exiting child pid when the last child process exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the call to `parentProcess()` outside the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_forks; i++) {
    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid < 0) {
        perror("fork\n");
    } else if (child_pid ==  0) {
        childProcess(i, goal);
    }
}
parentProcess();
```

Otherwise, the parent waits for each child in turn before running the next.

You should be using `wait()` or `waitpid()` in a loop inside `parentProcess()` to collect all the children as they die — and you may do well to provide `num_forks` as an argument to `parentProcess()`. Or you need to redefine what you want done. The question suggests that you want the children running simultaneously, while the parent waits for them all to die. That means you have to launch all the children before waiting for them — subject to not running out of processes (so `num_forks` is a sane number like 20, not an insane number like 2,000 or 2,000,000).

So, your code in `parentProcess()` should be roughly like this, as a basic minimum:

```
void parentProcess(void)
{
    int status;
    int corpse;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != -1)
        printf("%5d: 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
}
```

And this should be called outside the loop.  If called inside the loop, the parent will launch one child, wait for it to finish, then repeat the process.  I assume that the `childProcess()` function never returns; it will lead to chaos if it does return.

Comment: But then I only get to the parentProcess once. I need the parentProcess() to print something every time any child returns. I'm using `wait(&exit_id)` to wait for the child process to finish. Btw this is homework and I would prefer you explain the concept rather than give me code. Unfortunately, my professor is not very helpful.

Comment: You should be using `wait()` or `waitpid()` in a loop inside `parentProcess()` to collect all the children as they die.  Or you need to redefine what you want done.  The question suggests that you want the children running simultaneously, while the parent waits for them all to die.  That means you have to launch all the children before waiting for them — subject to not running out of processes (so `num_forks` is a sane number like 20, not an insane number like 2,000 or 2,000,000).

Comment: I believe I have solved it now Jonathan. I a separate for loop right after the one that creates the child processes, I looping num_forks times again and calling parentProcess() each time. If you add that to your answer, I would happily accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: See the update — an alternative implementation of `parentProcess()` which embeds the loop in the function, rather than after the `for` loop.  You could certainly write the `while` loop after the `for` loop instead of in a function, but frankly, the function is probably neater.